# 500 Response while making POST request from AJAX to Flask

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, post, flask, http-status-code-500

Below is my functions.js file

```
var count = 1;

// get a tweet from backend
function display_tweet(){

    var req = {
        "index": count
    }
    .ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_tweet",
    data: '{"id":"' + count+'}',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
}
```

Below is my python app.py file

```
@app.route('/get_tweet',methods = ['POST'])
def get_tweet():


    #user_agent_received = request.get_json()
    #print("request is ",request.form)
    print("request ",request.get_json())

    global data_dict
    print(data_dict)
    input_map = dict(request.form.to_dict())
    print(input_map)
    index=input_map['index']
    index=int(str(index))
    final_dic={}
    final_dic["text"]=data_dict[index]["tweet"]["full_text"]
    return json.dumps(final_dic)
```

Below is the stub from my index.html file

```
<div class="tweet">
            <div class="data">
                <button onclick="display_tweet()">display a new tweet</button>
                <div id="fulltextt"></div>
            </div>
```

I keep on getting an empty json with 500 internal error at backend which looks something like this. Please can someone help

```
{}
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2020 23:02:07] "POST /get_tweet HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: I think you're not passing a valid JSON. Check the 'data' filed inside the AJAX POST. 
data: '{"id":"' + count+'}'  -> '{"id":"' + count+'"}'

Comment: Yes it was an issue. However now on clicking the button get_tweet POST request is not being made to server. Is there some error in ajax code ?